# type parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to create a type Pixel, and make it an instance of the Eq and Show class. However, i've been reading information from a lot of places, and got really confused with this.

Here's some info on the type i need to create:

I have to store two numbers (the position of the pixel and a value from 0 to 255).
Two pixels are equal if they have the same value, whatever their position is.
For the Show instance, i need to print the position and the value.

Here's my attempt at this:

```
type position = Float
type greyScale = Int
type Pixel = (position, greyScale)

instance Eq Pixel where
    greyScale == greyScale = True

instance Show Pixel where
    show position = position
    show greyScale = greyScale
```

is this a correct way to do it ?

Comment: And for more examples: [learnyouahaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type names have to start with a capital letter. So, your definitions actually should look like this, since you are only defining type synonyms:

```
type Position = Float
type GreyScale = Int
```

For `Pixel`: It looks like you wanted to define a data type, not just a synonym, so you should do something like this:

```
data Pixel = Pixel Position GreyScale
```

Next: The `Eq` instance compares two `Pixel`s, so you have to represent them as such:

```
instance Eq Pixel where
    Pixel pos1 greyScale1 == Pixel pos2 greyScale2 = greyScale1 == greyScale2
```

`greyScale1 == greyScale2` just compares the two `greyScales`, which is what you want.

Also, I would not recommend overwriting `Show` instances to assure that `read . show == id` holds. (You can automatically derive specific instances by adding `deriving (Instance1, Instance2, ..)` after the datatype declaration). Rather than meddling with it I would define separate functions:

```
showPosition :: Pixel -> String
showPosition (Pixel position greyScale) = show position
```

and

```
showGreyscale :: Pixel -> String
showGreyscale (Pixel position greyScale) = show greyScale
```